# Why is there a resistor in a cmos X-OR gate?

Tags: mosfet, cmos, leakage-current

While reading up on logic gates i came across this image on Wikipedia:
[image]

According to the article, the resistor on the supply voltage for the inverter is necessary to ensure that no current is leaked from the inputs to the output but i don't see how that would be possible regardless of the resistor being there or not.

From what i've read, one of the benefits of mosfets is that the input impedance is high and thus any current leakage would be insignificant.

The statement in the article is marked with a [citation needed] so i suspect it might be false but i can't find any information to confirm or disprove the statements validity.

Comment: I don't know much about the internal workings of logic gates, but it looks like it might limit the current from Vdd to Gnd if both transistors in the top right are briefly on during switching.

Comment: That makes sense, i guess the two mosfet's would dissipate a lot of heat and eventually burn out in case of high frequency switching.
That would be a problem for inverters in general though and i haven't seen any resistors in schematics for inverters.

Comment: I would agree with @Jack.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So, does this mean that there should also be a resistor in every inverter regardless of wether it is part of an X-OR or not?

Comment: Ahh, i think i found my answer!
I found this [link](https://www.google.com/patents/US3651340).
The patent in the link states that the resistor is used to limit the current when both transistors are on in order to reduce power drain.
I guess it's a method to save energy.

Comment: No, not to save energy but to protect the components. Both transistors can't be on in a steady state, only in transitions.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I can see that there could be potential damage to the components but why is the resistor not included in most schematics for inverters?

Comment: Because it doesn't have a logical functional meaning and will just clutter the *conceptual* schematic.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Good point!
It would be nice if this information was available along with the schematics in order to save people from damaging their transistors but i guess we don't live in a perfect world! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resistor limits the current shorted from VDD to GND by the output stage when both output transistors are conducting.

Some logic gates, such as 60-70's CMOS gates or 74LS, have a linear region whereby their input voltage can be moved through levels that produce a linear change of output.

This was/is very pronounced in CMOS gates. If a the input of a CMOS non-inverting gate is moved gradually up from GND to VDD, its output is GND until the input reaches a starting point, then its output quickly but gradually increases to VDD. All that time its output is transitioning, both output transistors are on to some degree and you're drawing excess current from your rail. The resistor stops the transistors pulling too much current and wasting it or damaging the gate.

What you want from an ideal logic gate input is for all voltages below a certain input threshold level to be seen as logic low and all those above to be seen as logic high. And an ideal push-pull logic gate would have an output which: drives high by turning its top FET(?) full on and its bottom FET completely off; drives low by turning its top FET completely off and its bottom FET full on. But this would use a lot more transistors than the current implementations of logic gates, so you'd get fewer on a chip.

If you look around, you'll see 74LS inverters used with crystals and capacitors to make oscillators by keeping them in their linear regions. You can't do that with their successor, 74HC(T), because they don't have a much smaller or non-existent linear region (would have to look which up).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with pass-transistor logic is that it doesn't provide full logic level swing. So ideally it should be used with regular CMOS logic to restore the levels.

The XOR-gate shown in the post actually can provide full logic levels in all cases. The problem that still remains is, that the levels are not restored in all cases. Assuming A is high and B is low, the input A is used to provide the high level at the output!

Now, this is a case where the high level is not restored. And since gates are rarely used isolated but in larger circuits where one gate drives another it is easy to imagine the the high level degrades from stage to stage and that the transitions between logic levels become slower. In particular if a few gates are chained where the input is passed to the output without restoring the logic level.

In such a case the inverter in the XOR gate is driven by a "weak" high signal such that the PMOS transistor is not fully turned off but conducting some current. The NMOS is almost fully turned on and a static current is flowing. To mitigate this problem the resistor is used as it provides negative feedback by reducing the gate-source voltage of the PMOS transistor.

Of course this doesn't solve the problem, but will help to have more such gates in cascade without the need to restore the high level.

Comment: So there is something to the Wikipedia explanation after all!
I still don't understand how it works though.
As i see it, adding the resistor will lower the current coming out of the inverter and when it reaches the two transistors it might let less current through from the second input which would be low if the output is high anyways.
How does this help stabilize the output?

Comment: Assuming A is high and B is low, the high level at the output is provided by the PMOS at input B. If the input of A is only a weak high, then the output could only be a weak low. The NMOS at the transmission gate of input B could conduct
some current and the low of B could (partially) propagate to the output.

Comment: Hmm, i don't see the scenario you are providing.
If A is high and B is low, the inverter ties the NMOS at input B to ground so source is low and drain is high and the PMOS in the inverter doesn't even allow any current from Vdd to pass.
Am i getting something wrong?

Comment: The signal propagates through the other NMOS, I've just made an update.

Comment: I'm still having some trouble understanding but i think I'm getting closer.
It's getting late though and i will not have time for the rest of the week so i might open a chat room instead next week.